# On Salesforce Flow Screen, how to create a lookup on custom object?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am able to create a lookup on Standard object `Contact` successfully by entering these details:

- Field API Name: `MasterRecordId`
- Object API Name: `Contact`

Now, I want to create a lookup on my Custom object `Retrieval_Recipe__c` using either it's Id or Name.

- Field API Name: `Name`
- Object API Name: `Retrieval_Recipe__c`

This can be saved correctly on the Flow, but when it's run, it produce this error:

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. 
[LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an 
error during value provisioning. Original error: 
[Field: Name is not a valid lookup field.]] 
Failing descriptor: {markup://lightning:lookup}
```

I tried to change into:

- Field API Name: `Id`
- Object API Name: `Retrieval_Recipe__c`

It still produces the same error, but the Field becomes Id. I change into every field the custom object has, the result is the same.

How can I provide users a simple look-up into an object's record?

---

Some screenshot details:

[image: Settings in Flow]

Settings in Flow

[image: Error shown when doing test Run]

Error shown when doing test Run

[image: The Custom Object's field configurations]

The Custom Object's field configurations

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a lookup functionality it has to start first with an object (any object) that has a lookup to the target object.

First go to another object (I will call this ObjectA) and add a lookup to the "Retrieval Recipe" object (ObjectB).

Then "object api name" then would be the true ObjectA api name and the "field api name" is the name of the lookup field on ObjectA that looks up the "Retrieval Recipe" object.

This will work even if you are adding the lookup to a screen on a third object (ObjectC) as long as user profiles have the right permissions.